# In Spring's rest controller (marked with @RestController), functions can return both model objects and a ResponseEntity object, which is better?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

As a Spring Boot noob, I just know that in the controller class, its public functions can return both model objects and ResponseEntity object. Something like

```
public List<Book> getBooks() {}
```

or

```
public ResponseEntity<Book> getBooks() {}
```

But my question is which is better when there are multiple choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have control over the HTTP response status if you use ResponseEntity, in addition to the content of the object itself.

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> getObject() {
  return new ResponseEntity<Object>(object, Httpstatus.OK);
}
```

For example, if you need to validate some data from the request before executing any action and you want to let your client know what happened through the HTTP status code you can choose between different options.

```
HttpStatus.CONFLICT
HttpStatus.CREATED
```

Here you can take a look on the different status codes:

[HTTP Status Codes](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

Comment: @Ibpeppers So `ResponseEntity<>` is more professional, isn't it :)

Comment: @Rui Yes, it's a more accurate way to handle your responses. With those status codes you will help your client to understand what happened with the request.

Comment: @Rui For example, if you make a POST request to your API trying to create a new user, if your response have the HTTP Status code 201 Created, will make easier to understand what happened, if the request was successful or not.

Comment: @Rui A way to handle the responses from the client is using the status code of the response so, if your client makes a request and waits for a response with status 200 OK, some logic will be applied or not.

Comment: @Ibpeppers Great! Thanks a lot for your reply :) This is what I would like to know and confirm

Answer (score 0):

Just to shed more light on what @lbpeppers has mentioned. Using a ResponseEntity has many advantages.
 1. The client need not look into the body of the message if the status code is something like 400 or 404, which is quite helpful
 2. In some cases the client is not interested in the body. All it needs is a status of the operation
 3. There are a lot of handy methods like `is1xxInformational`, `is2xxSuccessful`, `is3xxRedirection`, `is4xxClientError`, `is5xxServerError` in HttpStatus calss which can be used like

```
response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()
```